# Compile error 'named argument not found'

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

Excel 2007

```
Sub Filtered_data_on_othersheet()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim xx As String

    For i = 1 To 3
        On Error Resume Next
        xx = Sheets("main").Range("K" & i).Value
        Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter field:=1, Criterial:=xx
        Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Copy Destination:=Sheets(xx).Range("A1")

    Next
    Err.Clear
    Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple mistake.  It should be `Criteria1` not `Criterial`

Use the number `1` instead of the letter `l`.