# VBA Excel text to column data returns one row only

Tags: excel, vba

I am fighting with the code, which constantly returns one velue only. My amount of rows is flexible. Sometimes I have 10 sometimes 60, so i can't set the fixed range. The End(xlDown) doesn't help too.

To clarify roughly my problem I am showing the code and output image below:

```
 Sub Texttocolumns()
 Columns("E:E").Insert

 Range("E1") = "SAO"
 Range("D2", Range("D2).End(xlDown)).Texttocolumns _
 Destination:=Range("D2"), DataType:=xlDelimited, Space:=True
 Columns("D").AutoFit
 Range("D2", Range("D2").End(xlDown)).Copy
 Range("D2", Range ("D2").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).PasteSpecial _
 Paste:=xlPasteFormats
 Application.CutCopyMode = True

 End Sub
```

[image]

I tried another ways like, instead of `Range("D2")` I put `Range("D")`, what didn't work. The same as in Destination, where instead of Range("D2") I put Range("D2").End(xlDown), what triggered an error from debugger.

How can I make this whole list running properly?

Comment: [This is the right way to find the last row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba).

Comment: It's angry at ` Range("D2", Range ("D2").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).PasteSpecial _
 Paste:=xlPasteFormats`. That space between `Range` and `("D2")` means it's not formatted correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A TextToColumns Ride

The comments should help you change the code where I misunderstood. If not, feel free to ask for details in the comments below.

```vb
Sub TextToCol()

    Const rowTitle As Long = 1        ' Title (Header) Row
    Const FR As Long = 2              ' First Record Row
    Const colSource As Long = 4       ' Source Column
    Const colTarget As Long = 5       ' Target Column
    Const strTitle As String = "SAO"  ' Target Column Title (Header)

    Dim rngCopy As Range              ' Source Record Range
    Dim rngPaste As Range             ' Paste Range
    Dim LR As Long                    ' Last Record Row
    Dim LC As Long                    ' Last Record Column

    ' Insert a new column (Target Column) after Source Column.
    Columns(colTarget).Insert
    ' Write Target Column Title.
    Cells(rowTitle, colTarget) = strTitle

    ' Calculate Last Record Row (from bottom to top) in Source Column.
    LR = Cells(Rows.Count, colSource).End(xlUp).Row
    ' Check if there are any records (data).
    If LR <= 1 Then MsgBox "No Records!": Exit Sub
    ' Calculate Source Record Range.
    Set rngCopy = Cells(FR, colSource).Resize(LR - FR + rowTitle)

    ' To avoid Excel complaining about data in cells when using TextToColumns,
    ' disable DisplayAlerts.
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

        ' Apply TextToColumns on Source Record Range.
        rngCopy.TextToColumns Destination:=Cells(FR, colSource), _
          DataType:=xlDelimited, Space:=True

    ' Enable DisplayAlerts.
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    ' Apply Autofit on Source Column.and Target Columns.
    Columns(colSource).AutoFit
    ' Apply Autofit on Target Column.
    Columns(colTarget).AutoFit

    ' Calculate Last Record Column using Title Row.
    LC = Cells(rowTitle, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    ' Copy Source Record Range.
    rngCopy.Copy

    ' Calculate Paste Range.
    Set rngPaste = rngCopy.Offset(, colTarget - colSource) _
      .Resize(, LC - colTarget + 1)

    ' Paste formats of Source Record Range to Paste Range.
    rngPaste.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

    ' Turn off CutCopyMode.
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you are looking for. I've commented so it should be clear but feel free to ask any follow up questions below.

```
 Sub Texttocolumns()
 Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
 Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
 Dim LastRow As Long

 ws.Columns("E:E").Insert
 LastRow = ws.Range("D" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

 ws.Range("E1") = "SAO"
 ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 4), ws.Cells(LastRow, 4)).Texttocolumns Destination:=ws.Cells(2, 4), DataType:=xlDelimited, Space:=True
 ws.Columns("D").AutoFit
 ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 4), ws.Cells(LastRow, 4)).Copy
 ws.Cells(2, 4).PasteSpecial

 Application.CutCopyMode = True

 End Sub
```

Comment: Here I am getting error:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33070010/compile-error-named-argument-not-found
I changed my Sub to Texttocolumn, but is the same

Comment: Works well on my end. The sub name won't make a difference. Can you go to the sub and press F8 until you find the line containing the error?